# Fixed width number formatting python 3

Tags: string, formatting, python-3.x, string-formatting, fixed-width

How do I get an integer to fill 0's to a fixed width in python 3.2 using the format attribute?
Example:

```
a = 1
print('{0:3}'.format(a))
```

gives '  1' instead of '001' I want. In python 2.x, I know that this can be done using

```
print "%03d" % number.
```

I checked the python 3 string documentation but wasn't able to get this.

http://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Thanks.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Prefix the width with a `0`:

```
>>> '{0:03}'.format(1)
'001'
```

Also, you don't need the place-marker in recent versions of Python (not sure which, but at least 2.7 and 3.1):

```
>>> '{:03}'.format(1)
'001'
```

Comment: How does this approach work for a full column, where i have 1, and 211 for example and i want to have the output 001 and 211. Thanks

Answer (score 18):

Better:

```
number=12
print(f'number is equal to {number:03d}')
```

Answer (score 13):

There is built-in string method [.zfill](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) for filling 0-s:

```
>>> str(42).zfill(5)
'00042'
>>> str(42).zfill(2)
'42'
```

Comment: This works well in my application, where I need binary numbers: `bin(42)[2:].zfill(7)` gives `'0101010'`.  I don't know how'd I'd make the other answers work.

Answer (score 3):

In python 3, the prefered way is as follows:

- use f-string (formatted string literal)
- specify the width (the number after the colon) with a leading zero to indicate that you want zero rather than blank if the number is not larger enough.

For example:

```
a = 20
print(f"number is {a :03}")
```

Note that there is no space after the colon, otherwise the leading zero has no effect.