# Create numpy array with equal number of digits in each element

Tags: python, numpy

I wanted to create a numpy array with same number of digits in each element. Suppose:
`User_001, User_002,....,User_123`
How can I do this?
I tried as follows:
`a1 = np.array([f'User_{i}' for i in range(124)])`
But it gives me:
`User_1, User_2, User_3......,User_123` which I do not want. Any help?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869999/fixed-width-number-formatting-python-3/56311800.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go

```
import numpy as np

np.array([f'User_{str(i).zfill(3)}' for i in range(124)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solutions, but should do well.

```
a1 = np.array([f'User_{str(i).rjust(3, str(0))}' for i in range(124)])
# or
a1 = np.array([f'User_{str(i).zfill(3)}' for i in range(124)])
```